# Polymer this.push not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0

In Polymer 1.x I am trying to push data from my database to an array, but for whatever reason, it suddenly stopped working.

When running this code

```
ready: function(){
    var leserbriefRef = firebase.database().ref('leserbriefe');
        leserbriefRef.on('value', function(snap) {
          var n = snap.child('numLeserbriefe').val();
          console.log(n);
          this.lbriefe = [];
          for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
                this.push("lbriefe", snap.child('l'+(n - 1 - i)).val());
            }
        });
  }
```

I get this error message:
firebase.js:283 Uncaught TypeError: this.push is not a function

I don't know why. Earlier this week it still worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common gotcha among js beginners, basically the usage of the `this` keyword. The context of the `this` variable inside the anonymous function is not the one you intended (in this case, the element). To solve this, you can use closures[1], `.bind`[2], or the newer ES2015 arrow functions[3].

## Closure

```
ready: function() {
  // assign this to self
  var self = this;

  var leserbriefRef = firebase.database().ref('leserbriefe');
  leserbriefRef.on('value', function(snap) {
    var n = snap.child('numLeserbriefe').val();
    console.log(n);
    self.lbriefe = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
      self.push("lbriefe", snap.child('l'+(n - 1 - i)).val());
    }
  });
}
```

## .bind

```
ready: function() {
  var leserbriefRef = firebase.database().ref('leserbriefe');
  leserbriefRef.on('value', function(snap) {
    var n = snap.child('numLeserbriefe').val();
    console.log(n);
    this.lbriefe = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
      this.push("lbriefe", snap.child('l'+(n - 1 - i)).val());
    }
  }.bind(this)); // bind this keyword to element's
}
```

## ES2015 arrow function (might as well go full ES2015)

```
ready() {
  const leserbriefRef = firebase.database().ref('leserbriefe');
  leserbriefRef.on('value', (snap) => { // arrow functions!
    const n = snap.child('numLeserbriefe').val();
    console.log(n);
    this.lbriefe = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
      this.push("lbriefe", snap.child(`l${n - 1 - i}`).val());
    }
  });
}
```

**Sources:**

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

[3] https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Great answer Neil!

Comment: I originally used ES2015 (I guess that's why it worked), but since firebase hosting for whatever reason does not really work well with ES2015, I had to use the old code.

Answer (score 2):

well you have to watch for `this` binding, since the scope of `this` is changes inside functions.

```
ready: function(){
    var leserbriefRef = firebase.database().ref('leserbriefe');
        leserbriefRef.on('value', function(snap) {
          var n = snap.child('numLeserbriefe').val();
          console.log(n);
          this.lbriefe = [];
          for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
                this.push("lbriefe", snap.child('l'+(n - 1 - i)).val());
            }
        }.bind(this));
  }
```