# Call this.push in Polymer({ }) function from HTML5's geolocation callback

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
_handleResponse: function (data) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude,
                lng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.push('thread.messages', {
        latlong: lat+","+lng,
    });

    }, function() {
        console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
    });
}
```

In the above, I get an error saying `push` is not a function. How should I handle this?

Comment: @a1626 Perfect. `var self = this` inside `_handleResponse `; and then in place of `this` I used `self`. Problem Solved !

Comment: Wrong `this` context : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306772/polymer-this-push-not-working/39308178#39308178

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal Yup, that was the problem.